# Enable Mixed Content | Safari | "Mixed Content: This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS

Tags: http, https, safari

```
Mixed Content: The page at 'https://yourwebsite.com/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint 'http://otherwebsite.com/'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
```

After running into this error a few times, I have learned in modern web browsers you cannot have mixed content. That means an https site cannot make a request to one that is just http.

So my issue is enabling this in safari.

---

However in the development stages I am able to enable this in chrome

1) Click on the shield.

[image]

2) Click "Load Unsafe Scripts"

[image]

3) Now you should be able to see the blocked content. but of course the website will no longer be secure.

[image]

---

I am also able to do this in firefox.

1) Click on the upside-down !

[image]

2) Click on the > arrow.

[image]

3) Disable protection for now.

[image]

4) Now the site is not secure, but your request/ content is available.

[image]

---

However, I have looked forever and cannot find this in safari for any of the recent versions. Even when enabling developer tools, I am unable to find it. I looked through some of the release logs to see if this feature was deprecated, and could not find anything.

Is there any way to do this in safari?

Answer (score 0):

I've done a bit of research and unfortunately Safari doesn't seem to provide an option to disable blocking mixed content loading from HTTPS to HTTP resources. If you want you can read the complete [discusson why they're not providing that in this ticket](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=171934).

As far as i know there's no easy way to fix this. You could either try:

1. To serve your HTTP resources over HTTPS.
2. To serve your HTTPS resources over HTTP.

The latter might be easier, but is of course more insecure. Whether or not that's a problem for your usecase is something you need to decide yourself.

Answer (score -1):

Mixed contents are disabled from Safari 9+
so this is not possible. you need to use workaround like proxy

Comment: Answers like this really are of no benefit. Why answer the question if you're not going to put in an example or at least give an explanation as to how the proxy would solve the issue.

Answer (score -3):

Navigates to your Safari "Privacy Settings" and disable the 'Block Third Party Cookies' and 'Disable Cross-site tracking' settings.